# htaccess password protect files with different users

Tags: apache, .htaccess, authentication, .htpasswd

I have a files server and I use mod_autoindex to server the files. I have a username and password in htaccess so only certain people can access the files. I have added another user to htpasswd but I would only like that user to access some of the files/folders.

Here is my htaccess file now:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "restricted"
AuthUserFile E:\\path\\to\\.htpasswd

<Files "filesForAnyUser\\*">
  Require valid-user
</Files>

<Files "*">
Require user admin
</Files>
```

I'm sure I am doing something wrong but I can't find any good documentation on this.

Comment: What is "filesForAnyUser"? Is that a folder?

Comment: ya that is a folder with files that should be available to any user

Comment: `E:\\path\\to\\.htpasswd` consider changing it to `E:/path/to/.htpasswd` using the opposite slash will save you some trouble in some specific situations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a folder called "filesForAnyUser" and a folder where you have files only for admin, you need to make 2 htaccess files. One in "filesForAnyUser":

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "restricted"
AuthUserFile E:\\path\\to\\.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

And one in the other directory:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "restricted"
AuthUserFile E:\\path\\to\\.htpasswd
Require user admin
```

Comment: that worked but why doesn't the <Directory> or <Files> directives work?

Comment: @UziTech Both [Directory](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory) and [Location](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#location) have contexts of "server" and "virtualhost" config. **Not** "htaccess", so those directives can't be used in an htaccess file, which makes sense because putting an htaccess file in a directory is kind of like using a `<Directory>` on that directory.

Answer (score 3):

So here is my final solution for anyone else.

Put the following in the root folder:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "restricted"
AuthUserFile E:\\path\\to\\.htpasswd
Require user admin
```

Put the following in any folder where admin and user1 can access the file:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "restricted"
AuthUserFile E:\\path\\to\\.htpasswd
Require user admin user1 #users separated by space or "Require valid-user" if all users
```

If you want to allow user1 to only access certain files you can use `<FilesMatch>`:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "restricted"
AuthUserFile E:\\path\\to\\.htpasswd
Require user admin
<FilesMatch "^(doc1.pdf|doc2.txt|doc3.docx)$">
  Require user admin user1 #or valid-user
</FilesMatch>
```

This gives admin access to all files in that folder but user1 only access to the files listed in `<FilesMatch>`

Note: The files in `<FilesMatch>` are for the current directory and any sub directory. I'm not sure how to limit it to only the current directory.